# Exact cause of hash code collisions in HashMap

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashtable

I know how hashmaps work and how they resolve collisions. But many answers related to collisions on SO point to two reasons:

- HashCode contract - unequal objects can have the same hash code
- Underlying array size - is fixed in size and hence bucket locations may be reused (using modulo operator) when it gets full.

My assumption is that reason 2 above is also correct, as am sure of reason 1.

Only 1 question:

- **Javadoc says that the hashmap uses LF and Capacity to decide when to rehash. I understand this as partly resizing the underlying array. So how is reason 2 above even possible?????**

**NB:** [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35082909/hash-collisions-in-hashmap) came closest to what I want to understand. However, the accepted answer seems to discard reason 2 altogether, so it still leaves me wondering.

Comment: Hashmap resizes according to capacity (when LF * capacity < size) or if there is a collision detected.

Comment: @LaurentB That's not true. Resize doesn't happen if a collision is detected.

Comment: @Kayaman sorry yes  reread the source (1.7) only when bucket is full and capacity reached

Comment: @LaurentB my question is how does the size of the underlying array cause collisions?

Comment: Well, a smaller array has a higher chance of collisions obviously. If you decided randomly whether to throw 2 balls in 2 buckets or 10 buckets, which would be more likely to end up with 2 balls in the same bucket? Are you sure you know how hashmaps work?

Comment: @Kayaman this now makes a lot of sense. The analogy of 2 balls has just increased my understanding of how hashmaps work :)

Comment: That's good. Analogies are quite useful in the computing world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reason 2 is flawed. A bucket may be reused even if there are plenty of empty buckets if adding two (unequal) objects that end up in the same bucket (hashcode % buckets.length). There's no "getting full" element here, except that as buckets get filled there's obviously a greater chance of ending up in a non-empty bucket.